# apex Map.clear() vs new Map?

Tags: apex

So I have an map created

```
Map<String,Opportunity> mapIdOpp = new Map<String,Opportunity>();
// do something with the mapIdOpp
```

Now I want to reuse the map variable. Do I use

```
mapIdOpp.clear()
```

or

```
mapIdOpp= new Map<String,Opportunity>();
```

Comment: There is not enough context to answer this question, but if your map is `final` you can only do the former.

Comment: @AdrianLarson the context is enough it's a valid quesiton. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757868/map-clear-vs-new-map-which-one-will-be-better.  If you want to remove the post just do it.

Comment: I would have voted to close it for that reason if I thought it appropriate to do so but I do not. As a duplicate however...

Comment: sfdcnoob the lack of context is with the "do i use ?" which doesn't specify any criteria to provide an answer or comparison to. You can obviously do both of your proposals. This current question is like asking us whether you should drive your red or blue car today, without any other info. Please update your question to specify what information you want to see in an answer (= a specific question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use either method, as they are semantically the same. However, as noted in the comments, sometimes you can only use one method or the other. For example, some maps are immutable and cannot be cleared (mostly those returned by system calls), and some variable are final and cannot be altered (mostly those specified by a developer). In some particularly rare cases, you might have a final immutable map, in which case you can't do anything with it at all.

So, it comes down to preference. I personally tend to create a new map when I need it rather than simply clearing the old one, which fits the paradigm of how I like to program. Others may prefer to simply clear the existing map. There's no "wrong" way to go about it, as long as you're consistent.

Comment: Is there any differences in efficiency, memory consumption, etc.?

Comment: @LanceShi I thought about trying to figure it out, but it really shouldn't matter in the grand scheme of things. After all, clearing/constructing the *same* map over and over again should be exceptionally rare, and if not, then I would imagine the performance gains either way would be minuscule compared to the overall performance of whatever the code is trying to do. I did once use code that involved repeated cloning/clearing of lists, and it didn't seem to be terribly inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to sfdcfox's response :

Another consideration might be based on memory utilisation. As salesforce is taking care of memory allocation and management on behalf of users, it won't make much difference.

But if you are working with big datasets and have a map which is no more utilised, I would rather prefer to clear it [and reuse , if its fitting my requirements].